# jQuery.noConflict() alternate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I just want to know that is there any difference between

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

and

```
//IIFE - pattern
(function ($) {
 ....
})(jQuery);
```

Because I saw someone doing that. is it alternate method of avoiding error : **error '$' is undefined** caused due to jQuery version conflicts ?
is it possible that jQuery ui also cause version conflicts?

Comment: Not specifically, no. The latter is a much better solution IMO, and one that should be used in all production environments, regardless of concerns over `$` variable conflicts.

Comment: Thanks Rory McCrossan for reply, I just need to know that in my project i've implemented $ sign in multiple js, i dont want to chng each instance, so is there any alternate way of avoiding conflict situation.